# convert taglists to html in R

Tags: html, r

Is there a way to convert taglists in R to HTML

```
                sapply(c("asd" ,"df" ), 
                       function(i)       
                         tagList(tags$option(value = i, paste0("selected>",i))))
```

Expected output

```
      <option value="asd" selected>asd</option>
      <option value="df" selected>df</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(purrr)
library(shiny)
library(textutils)

sapply(
  c("asd", "df"),
  function(i) {
    tagList(tags$option(value = i, paste0("selected>", i)))
  }
) %>%
  map(as.character) %>%
  reduce(~ paste(.x, .y, sep = "\n")) %>%
  HTMLdecode()
```

Comment: Thanks. But in output I am getting as ````&gt```` instead of arrow

Comment: @manup I revised my answer. You can decode HTML & symbols afterwards